# Using Google App Script I would like to copy these 3 rows with grouping from source to destination sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheet with 2 rows, grouped under 1 row. Using Google App Script I would like to copy these 3 rows with **grouping** from source to destination sheet.

I tried few options like targetSheet.getRowGroup etc but did not copy grouping. Any one who have a similar requirement and have achieved it?

Comment: We are not a code writing service.  If you have specific questions about  the code feel free to ask them, otherwise plan to develop most of the code on your own.

Answer (score 1):

```
function copyRowsWithGrouping() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("SourceSheet"); /* === source sheet === */
  var targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("DestinationSheet"); /* === destination sheet === */
  var startRow = 1, numRows = 3; /*=== start row and end row === */

  /* === Copy data === */

  var range = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sourceSheet.getLastColumn());
  range.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: false});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, that was super quick. I could not get this working, as it throws error as below `TypeError: targetSheet.groupRows is not a function` Similar to this i tried setRowGroups and it always says it is not a function, even in code helper i do not see these listed.

Comment: Hi @vraviz
I made some modifications to the original code to solve the problems you mentioned :)